# One variable equal to 0 in linear equation system.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a hard time getting a hang of a certain concept when it comes to linear equation systems.

Say that I have the equation system translated to a matrice:

\begin{matrix}
    2 & -2 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & -2 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}

Eventually what I will get is:

\begin{matrix}
    1 & -1 & \frac 32 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac 52 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}

\begin{matrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x-y+z=0 _1 \\ 
 y-z= 0 \\ 
z=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

And I was wondering if someone could explain how you're supposed to interpret the answer. Is z a free variable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ is not a free variable. If you were to continue your row reductions into RREF form, you obtain:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\,,$$

which shows that $x = y = z = 0$, i.e. you obtain a unique solution to the system.